# Is permittivity inversely proportional to electrostatic force?

Tags: electrostatics

In the formula $F = k \frac{q_1q_2}{r^2}$ where $k = \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon}$, is not the permittivity $\epsilon$ inversely proportional to the electrostatic force and therefore the strength of the electric field? This seems counter-intuitive, since I would expect high permittivity of a substance to allow a stronger electric field. Am I missing something? Apologies for my overbearing ignorance...

Answer (score 3):

I think it is just a misunderstanding of what permittivity is. It is a measure of resistance to forming an electric field in a particular medium. So high permittivity is equivalent to saying there is a high resistance to your electric field being produced here. Therefore, the field strength will appear to be weaker and (obviously) vice versa. Hope this helps.

Comment: So why it is named permittivity and not resistance?

Answer (score 3):

First, in the SI system, $k=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0\kappa}$

where $\kappa=$ is the dielectric constant and $\epsilon$ is the absolute permittivity

I think that the word, "permittivity" is misleading you. It sounds as though a material with higher permittivity should "permit" a stronger field to exist. The opposite is true. Electric field is inversely proportional to permittivity.

As the permittivity of a material increases, so does its tendency to reduce an external electric field.

Comment: So why it is named permittivity and not resistance?

Answer (score 1):

Permittivity is not inversely proportional to electric force . It tells us about the number of electric field lines of electrostatic force that can pass through a medium. It basically depends on the nature of the material.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically you are correct, for two given charges $q_1, q_2$ separated by a distance $r$ in a medium with permittivity $\epsilon$, then if the permittivity doubles, the force will decrease by a half. However, it is usual to argue that the size of $\epsilon$ determines the size of the resulting force rather than the other way around.